# C# RestSharp How to set "Connection" header to "keep-alive"?

Tags: c#, header, restsharp, keep-alive

Good evening,

I'm trying to set HTTP Header "Connection" to "keep-alive" this way:

```
client.AddDefaultHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
```

or

```
client.ConfigureWebRequest(r =>
{
    r.KeepAlive = true;
});
```

or both ways.

But nothing seems to be working. Charles keeps telling me that there is not "Connection" header in my requests.
RestSharp sets Keep-Alive header for GET requests automatically, but I don't have any ideas how to do it for POST.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set 'Content-Type' header using RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815065/set-content-type-header-using-restsharp)